# Отношение ManyToMany внутри одной модели в JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entity

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Столкнулся с проблемой описания сущности и связей таблицы.

Есть 2 таблицы:

1. Первая - `users (user_id, username)`
2. Вторая `user_friendship (id, first_user_id, second_user_id)` с двумя внешними ключами на первую:
   `first_user_id, second_user_id` - ссылаются на `users.user_id`

Не могу даже представить как описать энтити и джоины, даже не знаю с какой стороны начать.

**Вопрос**: как описать сущности и какие связи будут (`ManyToMany`)?
Использую `Spring boot data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классический случай many-to-many с самим собой.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_friendship", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "first_user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "second_user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false))
private Collection<User> friends;
```